# rmagick doesn't work after update from snow leopard to lion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xcode, ruby-on-rails-3, bundle, rmagick

I upgraded (not a new install) from snow leopard to lion. Now rmagick doesn't work. I updated Xcode, tried to reinstall the gem (as mentioned here: [rmagick and OS X Lion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6589066/rmagick-and-os-x-lion)), removed the 1.9.2 ruby from rvm, updated rvm and reinstalled the ruby 1.9.2 ans still get the following error:

Full trace see: http://pastie.org/2278596

```
mkmf.rb:368:in `try_do': The complier failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
```

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [x86_64-darwin11.0.0]

$ rvm --version
rvm 1.6.30 by Wayne E. Seguin (wayneeseguin@gmail.com) [https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/]

$ la /Developer/SDKs/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x   4 root  wheel  136 25 Jul 14:39 .
drwxrwxr-x  15 root  admin  510 25 Jul 14:45 ..
drwxr-xr-x   7 root  wheel  238 13 Jun 20:21 MacOSX10.6.sdk
drwxr-xr-x   7 root  wheel  238  4 Jul 02:18 MacOSX10.7.sdk
```

mkmf.log: http://pastie.org/2278612

Does anyone have a solution?

Thx!

Comment: I've got the same error!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it! After 2 days headache I figured out. Finally I think Imagemagick and homebrew where the problem. I removed homebrew completely and reinstalled ghostscript and imagemagick.

that's it

Comment: I ended up having to just reinstall imagemagick through homebrew, myself; glad you figured it out!

Answer (score 1):

Remove imagemagick and reinstall it with:

```
brew install imagemagick --disable-openmp
```

.. and go on.

I took this solution from

[Stack Overflow - Mac Rmagick wont install with Xcode 4.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961091/mac-rmagick-wont-install-with-xcode-4-2)