# Upgrade to Lion, failed to build gem native extensions

Tags: macos, rubygems, osx-lion, rmagick

Not sure if my problem is related to this thread (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6589066/rmagick-and-os-x-lion), but I just upgraded to Lion; more specifically I purchased an new machine and migrated over my old profile.

I am unable to launch rails 3 because it cannot find rmagick, and I am unable to install rmagick, because I get the following error. I tried uninstalling rmagick and imageMagick, but I still get the same error when attempting to bundle install. Any thoughts?
Thank you

```
Installing rmagick (2.13.1) with native extensions /opt/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/installer.rb:551:in `build_extensions': ERROR:     Failed to build gem native extension. (Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError)

    /opt/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
checking for Ruby version >= 1.8.5... yes
checking for /usr/bin/gcc-4.2... no
No C compiler found in ${ENV['PATH']}. See mkmf.log for details.
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
--with-opt-dir
--with-opt-include
--without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
--with-opt-lib
--without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
--with-make-prog
--without-make-prog
--srcdir=.
--curdir
--ruby=/opt/local/bin/ruby


Gem files will remain installed in /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rmagick-2.13.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rmagick-2.13.1/ext/RMagick/gem_make.out
from /opt/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/installer.rb:504:in `each'
from /opt/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/installer.rb:504:in `build_extensions'
from /opt/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/installer.rb:180:in `install'
from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/source.rb:101:in `install'
from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:78:in `preserve_paths'
from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/source.rb:91:in `install'
from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/installer.rb:58:in `run'
from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:93:in `with_build_args'
from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/installer.rb:57:in `run'
from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:12:in `each'
from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:12:in `each'
from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/installer.rb:49:in `run'
from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/installer.rb:8:in `install'
from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/cli.rb:222:in `install'
from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:22:in `send'
from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:22:in `run'
from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb:118:in `invoke_task'
from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:246:in `dispatch'
from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:389:in `start'
from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.15/bin/bundle:13
from /opt/local/bin/bundle:19:in `load'
from /opt/local/bin/bundle:19
```

UPDATE
So I updated to Xcode4 and when I `brew --config` it still indicates that I am missing GCC stuff:

```
HOMEBREW_VERSION: 0.8
HEAD: 8368fe489bde47b8f201bfcfdf328944fdf7092b
HOMEBREW_PREFIX: /usr/local
HOMEBREW_CELLAR: /usr/local/Cellar
HOMEBREW_REPOSITORY: /usr/local
HOMEBREW_LIBRARY_PATH: /usr/local/Library/Homebrew
Hardware: quad-core 64-bit sandybridge
OS X: 10.7
Kernel Architecture: x86_64
Ruby: 1.8.7-249
/usr/bin/ruby => /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby
Xcode: 
GCC-4.0: N/A 
GCC-4.2: N/A
```

How can this be??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears that you need to install Xcode's Unix Development Tools.

You can install the Unix tools when you install Xcode from the Mac App Store: http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id448457090?mt=12

Comment: I'm hoping you're right. I had Xcode 3 actually, but I am currently installing Xcode 4. I've actually been running into even more problems since my original post. Lots of issues if I `brew doctor` and get the following error when I `brew update` `fatal: Unable to create '/usr/local/.git/index.lock': Permission denied
Error: Failure while executing: git checkout -q master`. Let's see what Xcode 4 does...

Comment: Yeah, Xcode 3 doesn't run on Lion. Install Xcode 4 and then you might have to reinstall Homebrew.

Comment: @Jeff Peterson Actually Xcode 3 does run on Lion, it's just that the installer doesn't let you install it. You can modify the installer package and it'll install (and run) just fine: http://anatomicwax.tumblr.com/post/7906770311/installing-xcode-3-2-6-on-lion

Answer (score 4):

I've tried all the methods mentioned here, nothing helped. 
This saved my day: 
https://gist.github.com/3182604

NOTE: 
1. Update XCode from Preferences/Downloads
2. Install X11.app
3.  And only then fix ImageMagick gem

Answer (score 0):

From the Homebrew installations instructions at https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/Installation

"1 Installing via the App Store only works for Lion users. For other versions of Mac OS X, see here. **If you do install via the App Store, you will need to run the “Install Xcode” app that is placed in /Applications.**"