# Rmagick issue after updating to 10.9 Mavericks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, rmagick

I've just updated to Maverick, and experienced some issue with Rmagick. I've already try those solution but none of them worked

[RMagick error after installing OS X Mavericks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19573134/rmagick-error-after-installing-os-x-mavericks)

[Rmagick errors when running Rails S after upgrading to OSX Mavericks 10.9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23465378/rmagick-errors-when-running-rails-s-after-upgrading-to-osx-mavericks-10-9)

[Xcode 4.4 and later install Command Line Tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329243/xcode-4-4-and-later-install-command-line-tools)

I've already uninstall/reinstalled rmagick, imagemagick, xcode and command line tool about hundred time, but nothing worked so far..

Here's the error

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rmagick:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/leogalley/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for Ruby version >= 1.8.5... yes
checking for /usr/bin/gcc-4.2... no
No C compiler found in ${ENV['PATH']}. See mkmf.log for details.
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/leogalley/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/ruby

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/leogalley/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rmagick-2.13.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/leogalley/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/extensions/x86_64-darwin-12/1.9.1-static/rmagick-2.13.2/gem_make.out
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Upgrade to Lion, failed to build gem native extensions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6853111/upgrade-to-lion-failed-to-build-gem-native-extensions)

Comment: no, xcode is installed on my machine