# Spree cant find ImageMagick even when it's installed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, spree

I run the following:

```
[~/rails_projects/mystore] $ spree install
dyld: Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenCL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libclparser.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/identify
  Reason: image not found
sh: line 1: 34594 Trace/BPT trap: 5       identify -version > /dev/null
Image magick must be installed.
```

and get a bad response. I have imagemagick installed, but for some reason it's not finding it. Any help?

Comment: @ErikEscobedo Can you confirm that ImageMagick was installed successfully. Run `identify -version` in terminal and share the results.

Comment: which convert put this command and post output here

Comment: How was imagemagick installed? I would recommend using homebrew.

Comment: Can you please run this and let me know the response: `convert -version` Also what is your Mac version? I have had some issues when I was on Lion.

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6589066/rmagick-and-os-x-lion